# Difference between remind and remember in Italian?

Tags: verbs

I would like to know how to differentiate 'to remember' and 'to remind' in Italian. From a basic search, it seems as though 'ricordare' is used for both cases.

There are three cases I can think of...

1) Someone remembering something.

Ex1: I remember you from the party.

2) Someone reminding someone else about something.

Ex2: I reminded him about the project deadline.

3) Someone stating that another person "reminds" them of someone else or is similar.

Ex3: You remind me of my wife Maria, you look just like her.

Grazie!

Comment: Yes, "ricordare" would  fit in all the sentences you are suggesting. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_inglese/Italiano/R/ricordare.shtml

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately there is almost never a 1:1 correspondence between words in different languages. Both *remember* and *remind* are usually translated with *ricordare*, and the meaning is inferred from context.

Your second and third meanings could also be translated as *rammentare*, although it is a considerably less common word.

Also your third meaning could sometimes be rendered with *riportare alla mente*, but this is used mostly with situations or events ("this reminds me that time I went lion hunting...").

Comment: Moreover, *rammentare* has the first meaning too...

Comment: "rammentare" is not used a lot

Comment: @user84976 Not in spoken Italian, no. And I did not even mention *rimembrare*... It is a pity that the richness of our language is so underutilized.